# Check for active/qualified session in EventSubscriber, destroy session and cookies if not

Tags: authentication-authorization, 10, event-subscribers

I have an application that has a custom SSO with a third party service. We are porting Drupal 7 code to Drupal 10 to continue the functionality. Previously we had a hook_init function that did the following:

- Check if the user is authenticated with specific role
- Check that the user has two valid cookies (used in API calls to the third party)
- If the user is authenticated with specific role but accesses `/user` paths, redirect them
- If the user is authenticated but no cookies, redirect to custom login
- If the user is anonymous but has cookies, unset the cookies to force a login

I am running into two issues, either I get an endless redirect loop or the cookies are not unset. On top of that it seems like the responses get cached - as long as the user is authenticated as this specific role I want to keep evaluating this in every request.

Here is the event subscriber:

```
  /**
   * Kernel request event handler.
   *
   * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent $event
   *   Response event.
   */
  public function checkMemberPresence(RequestEvent $event) {
    if (!$event->isMainRequest()) {
      return;
    }

    $uri = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->getPathInfo();

    if ($this->isMember() && !$this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->cookies->has('session')) {
      user_logout();
      $response = new RedirectResponse('/member/login', 302);
      $response->send();
      $event->stopPropagation();
    }

    if ($this->isMember() && preg_match('/^\/(user$|user\/).+/i', $uri)) {
      $response = new RedirectResponse('/member', 302);
      $response->send();
      $event->stopPropagation();
    }

    if ($this->currentUser->isAnonymous() && ($this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->cookies->has('session') || $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->cookies->has('session_expires'))) {
      $options = $this->sessionConfiguration->getOptions($event->getRequest());
      $cookie_domain = $options['cookie_domain'];

      $response = new RedirectResponse('/', 302);
      $response->headers->clearCookie('session', '/', $cookie_domain);
      $response->headers->clearCookie('session_expires', '/', $cookie_domain);
      $response->send();
      $event->stopPropagation();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Helper method to check if the current user is a member.
   *
   * @return bool
   *   If the current user is a member.
   */
  protected function isMember() {
    return $this->currentUser->hasRole('ticketure_member');
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    return [
      KernelEvents::REQUEST => ['checkMemberPresence'],
    ];
  }
```

The first two cases appear to work AFAICT (haven't written the tests yet) but the third does not.

How can I fix this to work and not cache the response? Furthermore, is this a proper porting of hook_init and should it be done this way in Drupal 10?

Update:

The cookie removal logic now appears to work (domain must be sent) - still unclear on if this is a good implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with setting a higher priority because you only depend on user authentication (priority 300) and want to run before other event subscribers like routing and dynamic caching:

```
KernelEvents::REQUEST => ['checkMemberPresence', 290],
```

Then don't send, return the response with the event:

```
$event->setResponse($response);
```

This stops propagation automatically.

However, this doesn't override the Internal Page Cache for anonymous requests with no Drupal session cookie but third-party cookies. If you want to handle those requests within the Drupal kernel you need to uninstall this module.

Comment: IPC is uninstalled, yeah.